# Saving a form in POST edit doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-4

I have a controller method in which I'm trying to save a form that was edited in the view.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ModifyContract(ModContract mod)
{
    // submit modified contract
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        OutlookMediaEntities1 db = new OutlookMediaEntities1();

        db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(mod, EntityState.Modified);

        // save changes
        db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("ContractDetails", "Contract", new { id = (int) ViewData["contractid"] });
    }
    else
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Missing necessary information");
        return View();
    }
}
```

I'm getting a InvalidOperationException on the db.ObjectStateManager... line. I saw something that said it might be because I didn't assign a primary key and noticed my ModAds class (below) didn't include a primary key. Added it but I get the same error. I tried doing a db.Attach(mod) as suggested by an answerer in my earlier question, but I get a compiler error. Attach takes as a parameter a "IEntityWithKey". So apparently my entity doesn't have a key, so I'm thinking something must be wrong with how I'm declaring the model stuff.

```
    public class ModContract
    {
        public int contract_id; // primary key?
        public string contract_name { get; set; }
        public List<ModAds> ads;

        public string print_product_id { get; set; }
        public string print_ad_option_id { get; set; }
    }

    public class ModAds
    {
        public int contr_ad_id; // primary key?
        public string name;
        public string product_name;
        public string adv_product;
        public List<string> editions;
        public double freq_disc;
        public double other_dis_dol;
        public double? other_dis_per;
        public string non_cash_note;
        public double non_cash_cons;
    }
```

Is there a way to specify what the primary key is? My model is kind of weird because I have a list of ModAds in ModContract as you can see. Not sure if that could be a problem. Also I tried adding getters and setters to all of the field to see if that was the problem but I got the same errors.

I also tried to save with `db.Entry(model).State = EntityState.Modified;` but it didn't work because I'm using EF 4.0.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

**EDIT**

I think I know what's wrong, the model was made from a bunch of different database tables, i.e. there's no table ModContract. I'm pretty sure I have to somehow disperse the model stuff into the appropriate tables and columns..

**EDIT 2**

Pastebin of OutlookMediaEntities1: http://pastebin.com/YyrhjGDA

**EDIT 3**

Here's the GET ModifyContract method that shows how I'm querying the database to make the model.

```
    public ActionResult ModifyContract(int id)
    {
        ViewData["contractid"] = id; // save id

        // get data from db
        OutlookMediaEntities1 db = new OutlookMediaEntities1();
        var cont = from printContractAd in db.print_contract_ads
                   from printContracts in db.print_contracts
                   where printContracts.contract_id == id
                   select new { printContracts.contract_id, printContracts.note }; // name

        // select the ads for this contract
        var ads = from printContractAd in db.print_contract_ads
                  from printAdOption in db.print_ad_option
                  from printContract in db.print_contracts
                  from printProduct in db.print_products
                  from contractAdCount in db.Contract_ad_edition_count
                    where printContractAd.print_ad_option_id == printAdOption.print_ad_option_id &&
                          printContract.contract_id == printContractAd.contract_id &&
                          printProduct.print_product_id == printAdOption.print_product_id &&
                          contractAdCount.contract_ad_id == printContractAd.contract_ad_id &&
                          printContract.contract_id == id
                  select new
                  {
                      printContractAd,
                      printAdOption,
                      printProduct,
                      printContract.IsSigned,
                      contractAdCount.CountFreq
                  };

        ModContract con = new ModContract();
        foreach (var c in cont) // only one
        {
            con.contract_id = c.contract_id;
            con.contract_name = c.note;

            break; // only one
        }

        List<ModAds> cads = new List<ModAds>();
        foreach (var ad in ads)
        {
            ModAds mad = new ModAds();
            mad.contr_ad_id = ad.printContractAd.contract_ad_id;
            mad.product_name = ad.printProduct.product_name;
            mad.adv_product = ad.printAdOption.name;
            mad.name = ad.printContractAd.note;
            mad.freq_disc = ad.printContractAd.frequency_discount;
            mad.other_dis_dol = ad.printContractAd.other_discount;
            mad.other_dis_per = ad.printContractAd.other_discount_percent;
            mad.non_cash_note = ad.printContractAd.non_cash_note;
            mad.non_cash_cons = ad.printContractAd.non_cash_discount; // consideration?

            // get editions
            var eds = from contractEditions in db.print_contract_editions
                      where contractEditions.contract_ad_id == ad.printContractAd.contract_ad_id
                      select new
                          {
                              contractEditions
                          };
            mad.editions = new List<string>();
            foreach (var ed in eds)
            {
                mad.editions.Add("Volume " + ed.contractEditions.vol.ToString() + " Issue " + ed.contractEditions.issue.ToString());
            }

            cads.Add(mad);
        }

        con.ads = cads;

        // bind dropdownlist ad options
        var printproductList = from printProduct in db.print_products
                               select printProduct;
        List<SelectListItem> products_list = new List<SelectListItem>();
        List<print_products> products = printproductList.ToList();
        foreach (print_products product in products)
        {
            SelectListItem temp_item = new SelectListItem();
            temp_item.Text = product.product_name;
            temp_item.Value = product.print_product_id.ToString();
            products_list.Add(temp_item);
        }
        ViewData["products_list"] = new SelectList((IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)products_list.ToList(), "Value", "Text");

        // return view with form to modify
        return View(con);
    }
```

**EDIT 4**

Here's the view too if it helps (I couldn't get it format right on here): http://pastebin.com/SZvzJ9FB

Comment: How's your setup by the way? Are you using code-first, database first, model-first?

Comment: Not sure. Another team started this project and we are taking over. How do I check?

Comment: I have not worked with EF for quite a while now so I can't answer that particular question. What I remember for Code-First is that you have a DbContext and no edmx file. But you may [look here for Model First](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ff830362.aspx), [Code First](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj193542.aspx), [Database First](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj206878.aspx). Reading those will give you more insights and knowledge to your project's tool-of-choosing. Also, help you determine what approach the other team took.

Comment: can you post code for OutlookMediaEntities1?

Comment: Uhh... Not sure where to get that. Would the GET ModifyContract method, where I query the db, help? Or maybe a database diagram? @BehnamEsmaili

Comment: hover over `OutlookMediaEntities1 ` and pres F12 it with get you to DataContext Source.

Comment: Oh cool! It's like a 1000 lines long though, and most of it is comments. Wish I could copy it without the comments. Made a pastebin of it though, and posted it above, check it out. @BehnamEsmaili

Comment: i asked you for `OutlookMediaEntities1` code but you have posted code for `ObjectContext`.

Comment: Oops I don't know how that happened. Updated the pastebin link, check it again. @BehnamEsmaili

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28356/discussion-between-behnam-esmaili-and-maus)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could tell EF that `contract_id` is the key:

```
public class ModContract
{
    [Key]
    public int contract_id;
}
```

and make sure that the database column that the property maps to is a **`PK`**. It may matter though that it's an `IDENTITY` or not based on how you use it.

Comment: Yes it's primary key. Btw the model classes are based on a bunch of database tables (i.e. there's no table ModContract), and some columns are not included, etc. Do I have do something different to save with a model like that? Probably...

Answer (score 1):

for updating an entity , the entity must be attached to `Data Context`.for doing this getting the entity from data context with `Single` method would be enough.
try changing your code like this :

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ModifyContract(ModContract mod)
{
    // submit modified contract
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        OutlookMediaEntities1 db = new OutlookMediaEntities1();

        var updatedMod = db.ModContract.Single(m=>m.contract_id == mod.contract_id);
        TryUpdateModel<ModContract>(updatedMod);
        // save changes
        db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("ContractDetails", "Contract", new { id = (int) ViewData["contractid"] });
    }
    else
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Missing necessary information");
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: The issue with this code is that `mod` came from the view and it already has the changes in it. If you query it again and use another instance then you will have to copy over the changes from `mod` to that new (queried) instance to get the update persisted.

Comment: Also there's no db.ModContract, check the edit to the original question.

Comment: `TryUpdateModel` does what you have said.it copies changes from mod to newly queried instance.and about db.ModContract, i predicted that.it is name of the property that exposes you'r `Mod` table in `Data context` class

Answer (score 0):

You can add the [Key] attribute  above your primary key in the ModAds class.